# Import Vue-Navigation-Bar Not working in Vue3

Tags: vuejs3

I'm trying to use the vue navigation bar npm package in my Vue 3.3.4 project but I've so far no success:

I'm getting the following warning in my console:

```
[Vue warn]: Failed to resolve component: vue-navigation-bar
If this is a native custom element, make sure to exclude it from component resolution 
via compilerOptions.isCustomElement. 
at <App> 
at <App>
```

I have a Navigation.vue
https://gist.github.com/xmr-dev/d45f5f17e7f9df47f6519bd60b5a68c9

This Navigation.vue is used in App.vue

```
<script setup lang="ts">
   import HomeView from './views/HomeView.vue';
   import Navigation from './views/Navigation.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <header>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <Navigation />
      <HomeView />
    </div>
  </header>
</template>
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Why does my navigation doesn't work? Is it the warning? I got not errors in the logs
2. I you take a look at the gist and then the import

   import VueNavigationBar from '../../node_modules/vue-navigation-
   bar/src/vuenavigation-bar.vue';

is working but

import VueNavigationBar from 'vue-navigation-bar.vue'; doesn't work and gives an error (cannot find module). Why is this?

package.json dependecy's

"dependencies": {
"vue": "^3.3.4",
"vue-navigation-bar": "^5.0.2",
"vue-router": "^4.2.2"
},

https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-navigation-bar

Comment: Consider reading [the documentation](https://github.com/johndatserakis/vue-navigation-bar) carefully.

Answer (score -1):

add

```js
export default {
  components: { VueNavigationBar },
  ...
}
```

Comment: I've added you're suggestion but that's giving the syntax error that I can't overload that method. Do you know a working example?

Comment: you need to add the line `components: ...` to the component you use `vue-navigator-bar` like `data` or `methods`

Comment: Yes I did, and the above comment is the output

Answer (score -1):

try `import VueNavigationBar from 'vue-navigation-bar';`